# In MCU, Hawkeye and Black Widow talked about Budapest. What really happened in Budapest?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In *The Avengers*, Black Widow and Hawkeye, alongside other Avengers were in a battle which I cannot remember. However, they were distinctly talking about the Budapest being similar to the battle they were currently in. What really happened in the Budapest?

Comment: For those of you who don't like that there is [an exact duplicate on SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17705/13217), you can vote on Meta Stack Exchange for [Crossover Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/191265), which would allow a single question to be shared on more than one site.

Answer (score 36):

As per [this answer on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/30897/24087), this is an example of a Noodle Incident.

From [this page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident) on TVTropes;

> "The Noodle Incident is something from the past that is sometimes referred to but never explained, with the implication that it's just too ludicrous for words - or perhaps too offensive for depiction - and the reality that any explanation would fall short of audience expectations.
>
> The key to this trope is that the audience is left to imagine what happened based on vague hints or clues, with funny (or scary) results.

In fact, that page directly mentions the line in question from *Avengers Assemble*;

> In Spy Fiction or similar tropes, the Noodle Incident is usually referred to by a place's name. **"This is just like Budapest!"** "Remember Helsinki?" "God, it's Rio de Janeiro all over again." Sometimes this is elaborated upon, but usually not.

So in short, we'll probably never know exactly what happened in Budapest, and it's likely that writer/director Joss Whedon doesn't either - it is simply a throwaway line that helps us infer a long history between Hawkeye and Black Widow, informing us of the dynamic they share without bogging us down in exposition.

Comment: Also a good joke, given that they "remember it very differently". Is there anyone who watched the film who **wouldn't** want to know what happened there? :-)

Comment: WARNING! [TV TROPES!](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5133/70236)

Comment: On a related note, this makes me long for a good Hawkeye/Black Widow movie, perhaps even pre-Iron Man, chronologically.

Comment: Ah, but you underestimate Joss Whedon. As it currently stands, he's probably not going to get the chance to tell us the story, but based on his other works, he probably had an idea about what happened as well as on when he wanted to elaborate on the incident. (Disclaimer: I am, without a doubt, a Joss Whedon fanboy.)

Comment: @VedranŠego Well, even if we all agreed we wanted to know, we likely wouldn't all agree on which version we want to know XD

Answer (score 5):

Per the new Black Widow movie, the Budapest scenario has been somewhat clarified.

> Budapest was where Hawkeye caught up with Natasha and brought her into SHIELD (as referenced in the Avengers movie).  Some additional details are given (arrow holes in the walls of Natasha's Budapest flat), Dreykov (who runs the Red Room) and his daughter (the one referenced by Loki during the interrogation scene in Avengers) who were supposedly killed by Natasha during the completion of her defection.  Hawkeye and Widow spent two days hiding in a vent inside a subway station while the Hungarian Police hunted for them.